# facebook and twitter access-keys like AWS has

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, access-token, access-keys

I am writing a desktop app, so webbased oauth circuit is not applicable to my needs.
now if you are an AWS customer you have your secret user/pass to own the account.
but you also can generate access-key secret-key to "share" with some pals, allowing them
to use your account without giving them the admin control.

for example, your developers or serverside-apps can connect to S3 buckets using 
access-keys, while creditcard info is safe.

i couldnt find the way to do exactly the same with FB or TW...

i want to provide my clients a service to work with their accounts, but i dont want them to tell me their usernames and passwords. instead of that, i prefer to ask them their "access-keys"

i am not sure if they can generate them (i mean, if those platforms offer the feature...)
i saw tweetdeck asking for user/pass info of each account.

can anybody tell me if FB or TW provide these feature ? and if so, what is the link to generate them ?